# Is it possible to set the gulp.src({base, cwd}) arguments when using vinyl-src-stream?

Tags: gulp

When using gulp, some parts of the pipeline benefit from a `base` or `cwd` option in the `gulp.src()`; however, I don't see a way to specify these options when the source is a `vinyl-src-stream`. Does this just not make sense for `vinyl-src-stream` or is there some other way to insert those options into the pipeline?